# Get the true length of a url server content

Tags: java, http, http-headers

Using the http Header I'm trying to get the length of a website call from the header using the http connection of java.. But the problem is that my result is not compatible with the true result found in differents httpheader online tools.

This is my Code :

```
public static URLConnection getConnection(String url) throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
   //    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
   //         "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux ; Android 6.0.1 ; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36" +
   //             " (KHTML, par exemple Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible ; Googlebot/2.1 ; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
        return conn;
    }
```

I call the contentLegth field from header but I get just as result 1037Bytes and the true value have to be : 128241 Kb

```
public static Boolean PageWeightFromServer(URLConnection c) throws IOException {
        int length = c.getContentLength(); // The weight of the page received in the responseHeader
        System.err.println(length +"Bytes");
        return (length>500);
    }
```

Comment: where do you obtain the "true value" (i.e. 128241kb) ? the `getContentLength()` method should return the value of `content-length` header field. What is the length of output of `getContent()` ?

Comment: I get it from the tool : http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/

Comment: the getcontentlength() method return 1037 as result

Comment: Actually you shouldn't rely on third party tool. You can easily count the length of your contents ( from `getContent()` )

Comment: you mean getContentLength() ?

Comment: No. To verify the value from `getContentLength()` is correct or not, you should compare with the length of `getContent()`